# django "Key 'up_file' not found in MultiValueDict: {}"

Tags: django-models, python-2.7

In my htmlpage I am having 100 fields
I am having a field for upload file which is optional for users.
When i submit the form with the file chosen and few other fields left blank,
it got saved into db.

At the same time when i try to submit the form without choosing the
file to be uploaded,it is raising error as ""Key 'up_file' not found 
in ""

**--models.py--**

```
class js_details(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    dob = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    sec_email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, null=True)
    address1 = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    address2 = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    up_file = models.FileField(upload_to='documents', null=True)
```

**--views.py--**

```
def newpost(request):
if request.method == "POST":
        user_id = request.POST.get('user_id')

        fname= request.POST.get('fname')
        lastname= request.POST.get('lastname')
        dob = request.POST.get('dob')
        sec_email = request.POST.get('sec_email')
        address1 = request.POST.get('address1')
        address2 = request.POST.get('address2')
        up_file = request.FILES['up_file']
       p = js_details(user_id=user_id,fname=fname,lastname=lastname,dob=dob,sec_email=sec_email,address1=address1,address2=address2,up-file=up_file)
       p.save()
```

How to save the form without the file field filled.?

All ur answers are welcomed.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using `request.POST.get` for POST data and not for `request.FILES` ? Looks like you are programming by accident... 

I strongly suggest you take some times learning Python and Django (hint: both have good tutorials and a fairly extensive documentation).

Comment: I am very new to python and django, and learning myself, basically i am from core side.. So dont mistake me with my silly errors..

Answer (score 0):

To strictly answer your question : you are using a subscript access on request.FILES (=> `request.FILES['up_file']), which indeed raises a`KeyError`if there's no matchinh key. You should use`request.FILES.get('up_file')`and check the returned value which will be`None`if the user didn't post a file. Read the Python's doc about`mapping`and`dict` for more on these data types.

Now there's another problems with your code. The first one is that you blindly accept any user input without validation, sanitization and data type conversion. Using a `ModelForm` would take care of this and simplify your code.

Also and as side note, you should really stick to Django / Python naming conventions and use CapCase for your class names.

Here's a fixed version of you're code:

```
# models.py 
class JsDetails(models.Model):
    # ForeignKey -> OneToOneField, 
    # cf https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/fields/#onetoonefield
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True)
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    # I assume "dob" means "date of birth"
    # so CharField -> DateField
    dob = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    sec_email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    address1 = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    address2 = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    up_file = models.FileField(upload_to='documents', blank=True, null=True)

# forms.py
from .models import JsDetail
from django import forms

class JsDetailForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        models = JsDetail

# views.py
from .forms import JsDetailForm 
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render

def newpost(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = JsDetailForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newdetail = form.save()
            redirect("/somewhere/to/show/the/result")
        # if the form is not valid it will be redisplayed
        # to the user with error messages

    else:
        form = JsDetailForm()

    return render(
        request, 
        "your/template.htm",
        dict(form=form)
        )
```

There are still problems with this code IMHO but that's still an improvement. I very strongly suggest you take some time doing the Python tutorial and the Django tutorial, it will save you a whole lot of pain and trouble.